# How to return Error Response to a user from a middleware

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am new to Rust and the Actix web framework. I have been trying to create a simple server in actix web. I have implemented the auth system but I am trying to create a middleware for verifying the JWT token and extract the claims from the jwt to be used in an handler.

```rust
impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for JwtVerifierMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    forward_ready!(service);

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let authorization = req.headers().get("Authorization");

        let mut extensions = req.extensions_mut();

        let fut = self.service.call(req);

        let token = if let Some(authorization) = authorization {
            authorization.to_str().unwrap()
        } else {
            return Box::pin(async {
                let res = fut.await?;
                Ok(res)
            });
        };

        let claims = verify(token).unwrap();

        extensions.insert(claims);

        Box::pin(async move {
            let res = fut.await?;
            Ok(res)
        })
    }

}
```

I have the code above where I am trying to extract the token from the request and return an error response if the token is a `None` variant.The issue I have currently is that `self.service.call()` wants to move the req but it has already been borrowed here `req.headers().get("Authorization")`. I am not sure how to approach this.

I have tried to clone the `req` but it seems `ServiceRequest` does not implement the clone trait. I have also tried to pass a reference to the `ServiceRequest` as argument to the `call` function but I get an error that method `call` has an incompatible type for trait `Service`

Comment: Wouldn't you call `self.service.call(req)` after auth checks rather than before?

Comment: I am trying to check if the token is present at all before verifying the token. So that I can return an error early if the token is not present before getting to the verification part.